# Let $R_1$ and $R_2$ be the “congruent modulo 3” and the “congruent modulo 4” relations, respectively. Find $R_1\cap R_2$ and $R_1 \cup R_2$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I have this question and would need help on how to find **$R_1 \cup R_2$**. My working for $R_1 \cap R_2$ is shown below:

Let $R_1$ and $R_2$ be the “congruent modulo 3” and the “congruent modulo 4” relations on the set of integers respectively. 
That is, $R_1 = \{(a,b)\ |\ a \equiv b(mod\ 3)\}$ and $R_2 = \{(a,b)\ |\ a\equiv b(mod\ 4)\}.$ Find $R_1\cap R_2$ and 
$R_1 \cup R_2.$

For $(a,b) \in R_1 \cap R_2$:

$a - b = 3r$ for some $ r \in \Bbb{Z}$ and

$a - b = 4t, $ for some $t \in \Bbb{Z}.$

Therefore, I can conclude that $a - b = 12k$ for some $k \in \Bbb{Z}.$

Hence, $R_1 \cap R_2$ implies that $a \equiv b(mod\ 12).$

Comment: Yes, your work is correct: $\;R_3\cap R_4=R_{12}\;$ +1

Comment: What do you mean by "find" $R_1\cup R_2$? It's the set of all $(a,b)$ such that $a\equiv b\bmod3$ or $a\equiv b\bmod4$. Is that good enough?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.